# firefox-43.0.1 youtube - An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: firefox, youtube, user-agent

I have upgaraded today my firefox to version

firefox-43.0.1.tar.bz2 (64 bit)

Now i am seeing something wired. If i try to play the youtube videos then that does not work ( An error occurred. Please try again later ). If i start the firefox with the switch "-P"
and create a new profile then all works. Since i wanted to make my current profile work, i disabled all extentions and tried again. But that did not help. Then i enabled only the user agent switcher and live http headers addon. I notice that if i change the user agent from the default firefox to google chrome then all work as expected, but i can not understand why is the default user agent not working then?

Here is the default user agent http GET  to youtube.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: youtube.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is the modified user agent http GET  to google.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: youtube.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

That was always working with the default user agent. If i go to the html5 test page on youtube i see that all elements are enabled i.e.

HTMLVideoElement
H.264
WebM VP8 
Media Source Extensions
MSE & H.264
MSE & WebM VP9

So what i am missing here? Is there any particular string i should be looking in about:config?

PS: Cache, cookies are cleared anytime i restart firefox.

Comment: ok i found what was wrong i..e it was not the user agent . I can not explaing that thing with switching the user agent and why it was working but i went ot about:config and typed "media." and  reset all the values that i found there. Some of them are media.gmp-gmpopenh264.*  i do not know where they are comming from

Comment: Well, that sure helped; thank you!  For months I've been copying youtube eddresses into Safari or Chrome.<br/>Further information: the first thiing I tried was to set media.gmp-gmpopenh264.enabled to true; that did it.